# shadows not appearing in the scene in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, shadow

camera :

```
 Camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, Width / Height, 0.1, 10000);
 Camera.position.set( 150, 400, 400);
  Scene.add(Camera);
```

Light

```
 Light = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffccff,.5, 0, Math.PI/2, 1);

Light.position.set(0, 2000, 0);
Light.castShadow = true;
Light.shadowBias = -0.0002;

Light.shadowCameraNear = 850;
Light.shadowCameraFar = 8000;
Light.shadowCameraFov = 600;
Light.shadowDarkness = .7;

Light.shadowMapWidth = 2048;
Light.shadowMapHeight = 2048;
Scene.add(Light);
```

Renderer

```
 Renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true,
    sortObjects: false,
    preserveDrawingBuffer: true,
    shadowMapEnabled: true

});

    document.body.appendChild(Renderer.domElement);
    Renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
    Renderer.shadowMap.cullFace = THREE.CullFaceBack;
    Renderer.gammaInput = true;
    Renderer.gammaOutput = true;
    Renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
```

i use this function to add 3d model

```
 function getModel(path,texture) {

            var Material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({shading: THREE.SmoothShading,
                specular: 0xff9900,
                shininess: 0,
                side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                shading: THREE.SmoothShading

            });


           Loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
            Loader.load(path,function(geometry){

                geometry.mergeVertices();
                geometry.computeFaceNormals();
                geometry.computeVertexNormals();

                TextureLoader.load(texture,function(texture){


                Mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, Material);
                Mesh.material.map =texture;
                Mesh.material.map.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
                Mesh.material.map.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
                Mesh.material.map.repeat.set(38,38);
                //Mesh.position.y -= 1;
                Mesh.position.y = 160;
                    Mesh.position.x = 0;
                    Mesh.position.z = 0;
                Mesh.scale.set(40,40,40);
                Mesh.castShadow = true;
                Mesh.receiveShadow = true;
                Scene.add(Mesh);

                });
            });
        }
```

and the plane to recive shadow is

```
var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(100,100);
  var planematerial  = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial(
  {
    shininess: 80,
    color: 0xffaaff,
    specular: 0xffffff
  });

var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry,planematerial);
plane.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;
plane.position.set(0,100,0);
plane.scale.set( 10, 10, 10 );
plane.receiveShadow = true;
plane.castShadow = true;
Scene.add(plane);
```

I just tried adjusting the position of the lights and adjusted the values of shadowCameraNear,Light.shadowCameraFar and Light.shadowCameraFov  .but not no changes are seen

Comment: Maybe you can add a fiddle?

Comment: `Light.shadowCameraFov = 600;` ?

Comment: With a `Light.shadowCameraNear = 850;` most probably all your objects are not visible from the shadow camera.

Answer (score 1):

The camera is at (150, 400, 400), the object casting the shadow is at (0, 160, 0), the object receiving the shadow is at (0, 100, 0) and the shadowCameraNear frustum is set at 850.  That is, your camera is about 200 and 400 units from the two shadowing objects, respectively, but your shadow viewing near frustum is 850 units away.  Adjust your positioning.  You can set

```
Light.shadowCameraVisible = true;
```

to show the camera frustum in debug mode to help out.

Comment: Light.shadowCameraVisible is removed from three.js r73

Comment: @ArUn Thank you for pointing that out.  The documentation on threejs.org is out of date.  r73 itself will throw a console message:  "'THREE.Light: .shadowCameraVisible has been removed. Use new THREE.CameraHelper( light.shadow ) instead.'"  CameraHelper now "shows frustum, line of sight and up of the camera" so that should still help with positioning.  If changing the position solves the problem, please let us know and mark your question answered.